# Writing in a file.txt a Latex's format of tables with java

Tags: java, latex

I'm trying to automatically get files.txt with tables in latex's format, and so I want to write with Java the next String using `.write`

```
writer.write("\centering"+"\r\n");
```

But I'm not allowed to do so, eclipse marks "\centering" and says

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )
```

I tried separating  it like  "\"+\centering" but didn't work either
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash '\' by doubling it: `\\`

```
writer.write("\\centering"+"\r\n");
```